# How to validate Old Password , New Password & Confirm Password using FormGroup in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, validation, ionic2

I am trying to validate password by, old password, new password & confirm password in profile page.It should only check if **Old password** is entered. i tried to do it by Form Group but getting error.

error:

> Error in ./TextInput class TextInput - caused by: There is no
>   FormControl instance attached to form control element with name:
>   'old_password'

profile-edit.ts:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public 
   myForm:FormBuilder,public http: Http, public alertCtrl: 
   AlertController,public storage: Storage, public loadingCtrl: 
   LoadingController, public authservice: Auth) {
 this.profileForm = this.myForm.group({
   fname : ["", [Validators.required]],
   lname : ["", [Validators.required]],
   username : ["",Validators.required],
   email: ['', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$")
   ]],
   old_password:[''],
   password: [''],
   repeatPassword: ['']
   },{validator: this.areEqual});
}
areEqual(group: FormGroup) {
  var valid = false;
  const pwd1 = group.get('password');
  const oPwd = group.get('old_password');
  const pwd2 = group.get('repeatPassword')  ;
  let rv: {[error: string]: any} = {};
  if ((oPwd.value) && pwd1.value !== pwd2.value) {
     valid = true;
  }
  if (valid) {
    return null;
  }
  return {
     areEqual: true
  };
}
```

Form in profile-edit.html :

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
    <ion-list>
    <div class="field">
                        <ion-item>
                        <ion-label><ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                            <ion-input style="margin-left: 64px" type="text" formControlName="fname"  name="fname" placeholder="First Name" ngControl="fname"></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
    <div class="field">
                        <ion-item>
                        <ion-label><ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                            <ion-input style="margin-left: 64px" type="text" formControlName="lname"  name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" ngControl="lname"></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
    <div class="field">
                        <ion-item>
                        <ion-label><ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                            <ion-input style="margin-left: 64px" type="text" formControlName="username"  name="username" placeholder="Username" ngControl="username"></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
    <div class="field">
                    <ion-item>
                    <ion-label><ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                        <ion-input style="margin-left: 64px" type="password" formControlName="old_password"   name="old_password" placeholder="Old Password" ngControl="old_password" ></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </div>
    <div class="field">
                    <ion-item>
                    <ion-label><ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                        <ion-input style="margin-left: 64px" type="password" formControlName="password"  name="password" placeholder="New Password" ngControl="password"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </div>
    <div class="field">
                        <ion-item>
                        <ion-label><ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                            <ion-input style="margin-left: 64px" type="password" formControlName="repeatPassword"  name="repeatPassword" placeholder="Confirm New Password" ngControl='repeatPassword'></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
    <div class="field">
                        <ion-item>
                        <ion-label><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                            <ion-input style="margin-left: 64px" type="email" formControlName="email"  name="email" placeholder="Email" ngControl='email' disabled="true" ></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
    <div class="field regbtn">
                        <ion-item>
                            <button [disabled]="!profileForm.valid" (click)="presentConfirm()" class='login_btn'>Update</button>
                        </ion-item>
    </div>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

Comment: if you only want to check if old password is entered, why do you have custom validator for the new passwords? :) Also just adding `Validators.required` would just check that the old password is entered.

Comment: It should only check if Old password is entered.

Comment: Well, then I think `Validators.required` would be in place. Of course here you would also want to check that user hasn't entered whitespaces.